# Why does VS Code appear like that?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: vs code problem]

Why does VS Code appear like that?

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: what is the point of also having Google Chrome in the image

Comment: Duplicate of: [Why does VS Code give a chip-like / distorted display when I hover over it with my mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/2745495)