# Terminal window on vscodium appears pixelated

Tags: vscodium

The terminal window on vscodium looks so pixelated that its not practical to work on it (see screenshot).
I am using windows 10 pro 22h2 os build 19045.2604 feature pack Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0. I am using Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz   2.00 GHz with 8 gb ram.

I used chocolatey to install vscodium using powershell opened in administrator mode.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve it. I am relatively inexperienced.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKKcm.png)

I have no idea what to try to solve it.

Comment: I have tried restarting vscodium and re running the program but every time the terminal window appears heavily pixelated

Comment: possibly https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/11107541 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the two solutions below:

In Settings->Features, change the Terminal>Integrated>Renderer to canvas or dom.

In Properties, Under the Compatibility tab, click on Change high DPI settings and check the Override high DPI scaling behavior option.

Good luck.

Comment: I couldn't find the first option i.e. renderer to canvas or dom. changing the high dpi settings and checking the override high dpi scaling behavior option did not solve it. thank you for your suggestions!