# blurry/un-rendered/distorted popup notification on visual studio code in ubuntu22 running on virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualbox

I am facing all notification outages on visual studio code for pop up messages.

The set up is new, on virtualbox 7 with ubuntu 22.04.2 with classic vsc installed.
I have tried restarting, re-installing to no success. has this happened to anyone? Can anyone please suggest a possible fix?

[image]

##### in my case, adding the line does not work, but unticking the 3D acceleration does.

[image]

## Update 2024, window 11

Interestingly, after updating to windows 11 and remaking ubuntu 22.04.3 this fix did not work.

Instead, reducing the video memory to the default, 16 MB and ticking the enable 3D acceleration solved the issue.

Comment: Possibly [Why does VS Code give a chip-like / distorted display when I hover over it with my mouse?](/q/72962855/11107541)

Comment: wow, you are right ! if you will put that as the answer i will mark it as accepted! This is abit unfortunate though, ticking the 3D acceleration seem to make the vm smoother.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does VS Code give a chip-like / distorted display when I hover over it with my mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72962855/why-does-vs-code-give-a-chip-like-distorted-display-when-i-hover-over-it-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be another case of graphics accelleration problems. You can disable graphics acceleration following the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration

> - Open the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`).
> - Run the Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments command.
> - This command will open a argv.json file to configure runtime arguments. You might see some default arguments there already.
> - Add `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`.
> - Restart VS Code.

if running on windows virtual box, refer to the question post's screenshot.

Or as stated in the question post, try turning off 3D acceleration in the virtual machine settings.