# VSCODE UI partially unreadable on Ubuntu possible problem with rendering on VBOX

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualbox, ubuntu-22.04

I have recently installed VS Code from deb package "code_1.83.1-1696982868_amd64.deb" but it happens also when I install Code with apt. Part of the user interface is unreadable (for example "Save as" window looks like in the screenshot). Im working on Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome 42.9, Virtualbox Graphics SVGA3D;LLVM, Wayland with Oracle Virtualization.

[Save as window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXotR.png)

Tried using "--disable-gpu" or "--ozone-platform=wayland" but UI has the same problems, when I use both options VSCode doesnt even run. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: so https://stackoverflow.com/q/75655734/11107541 doesn't help? because it looks like a very similar question.

Comment: Removing "3D acceleration" using VBOX options worked for me, disabling gpu acceleration on VSCode level didnt, thanks for your help, I couldnt find this post probably because I wasnt able to name the problem properly. Thank you for your help!