# Screen Glitch while Coding

Tags: visual-studio-code, screen

Everytime is move my cursor in vscode while coding...the screen starts glitching
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUWRk.png)Any solution to this?

I haven't got any solution for this problem yet....so it would be great if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does VS Code give a chip-like / distorted display when I hover over it with my mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72962855/why-does-vs-code-give-a-chip-like-distorted-display-when-i-hover-over-it-with)

Comment: Yes thank you it fixed my problem