# Messed-up graphics in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu, VirtualBox VM)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, graphics, virtualbox

**EDIT: Disabling GPU Acceleration did NOT fix the issue** (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966747/how-can-i-disable-gpu-rendering-in-visual-studio-code/58762168#58762168)) 
**EDIT: Disabling 3D acceleration in the VirtualBox VM settings fixed the issue.**

I installed Visual Studio Code on a VirtualBox VM (running Ubuntu 22.04) a few days ago. Everything was working fine until about half an hour ago, when strange artifacts started appearing in any windows generated by VSCode.

The top bar of the VSCode window:
[image]

Trying to open a folder (Ctrl-K + Ctrl-O):
[image]

Trying to save a new file (Ctrl-S):
[image]

I think this is a VSCode-specific issue, because the Ubuntu File Explorer works just fine. Can someone help me find what could be causing this issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72962855/11107541

Comment: Had the exact same issue, also for me disabling 3D acceleration in the VirtualBox fixed the problem